# Arithmetic with << operator

Tags: c++, integer, int

New to c++, know the use of << in e.g:

```
 cout<<"hi";
```

but the following:

```
 int a = 1<<3;
 cout<<a;
```

will output 8; why is this I simply ask? How to I interpret the use of << here?

Comment: Do some research before asking on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The `<<` operator performs a bitshift when applied to integers.

1 in binary is 00000001. Shift it by three bits and you get 00001000, which is 8.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` in `1<<3` is bit-wise left shift operator not a stream insertion. It will shift `1` to left by three bits.

Answer (score 0):

The operation that every particular operator does and the result of that operation depends on what kind of type/object stands on its left and right side, so expect different results for different objects. As already explained, in this case it does a bitshift, because that is the operation defined for this operator, when both left and right elements are ints. In case of

```
cout<<"hi";
```

you have an std::ostream type on the left, and the std::string type on the right, and that is why the result of this operation is different - '<<' is in this case defined as an **insertion operator**; in case of two ints it is defined as a **bit shift operator**.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1<<3;
```

This is the "real" `<<` operator. It performs **bit-shifting**. You normally do not need such an operation in high-level code; it dates back to the old days, long before C++ existed, when there was only C and when programmers had to manually tinker with such things much more frequently than in today's world.

In order to understand what's going on, you need to know how binary numbers work.

A decimal 1 remains, coincidentally, the same in binary:

```
1
```

Now picture some zeroes in front of it (this usually makes it easier to understand for beginners -- leading zeroes do not change a number's meaning, neither in decimal nor in binary):

```
...00000001
```

The `<<` operation moves the bit to the left:

```
  moved by 3 positions
       +--+
       |  |
       v  |
...00001000
```

Now remove the leading zeroes:

```
1000
```

Here we go. Binary 1000 is 8 in decimal (1*8 + 0*4 + 0*2 + 0*1). For details and interesting corner cases, consult any good C++ book or online tutorial.

Now let's look at the other meaning of `<<` in C++:

```
cout<<"hi";
```

This is an **overloaded** operator. C++ allows you to take almost any built-in operator and give it a new meaning for different classes. The language's standard library does exactly that with `std::ostream` (of which `std::cout` is an instance). The meaning does not have anything to do with bit-shifting anymore. It roughly means "output".

Nowadays, it is considered bad programming style to take an operator and give it a meaning completely unrelated to its original one. Examples for accepted use of operator overloading are when the new meaning makes sense with the original semantics, e.g. when you overload `+` or `-` for mathematical matrix classes. However, when C++ was invented, this feature was apparently used more liberally.

This is why we are stuck with the completely different meaning of `<<` (and `>>`) today. In fact, the new semantics even seem to overshadow the original one for quite many beginners (as evidenced by your question).